# AWS S3 GET after PUT includes chunk-signature data

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After doing a PutObject to S3 of some simple text data and then retrieving that object back using GetObject, the object contains some extranneous `chunk-signature` data that I don't need, i.e.

```
n;chunk-signature=<hash>
my data
n;chunk-signature=<hash>
```

Is there any way through the .NET SDK to disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is to change `UseChunkEncoding` to `false` in the `PutObjectRequest`.

```
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = <bucket>,
                Key = <key>,
                InputStream = <stream>,
                ContentType = <contentType>,
                UseChunkEncoding = false                
            };
```